# What does exactly `operator` keyword do in kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mobile

today i saw a code which had a operator keyword in it, I went through kotlin docs and as i went more into it,  i couldn't understand what exatly `operator` keyword do. Can somebody explain it to me in a clean way?!

this is the code:

```
class ImageUseCase @Inject constructor(private val repository: GeneralDataSource) {
    suspend operator fun invoke(
        page: Int = 1,
        category: String = "latest"
    ) = repository.getAllImages(
        page = page,
        category = category
    )
}
```

thanks in advance. i'm new to kotlin!

Comment: [Have you seen this?](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html) Especially the invoke operator section.

Answer (score 0):

I will focus this answer on the special case of the `invoke` operator, since it is used a bit differently than the other operators.

Your example implements the use case pattern with dependency injection. In the end you want to use the use case just by calling a single function. What you have, however, is an entire class. And that's where the operator `invoke` helps out. In essence, it enables you to handle an *object* like a *function*.

Operators are just simple functions like any other, they just have an additional syntax associated with them. For the `invoke` operator it is making the enclosing object invocable, i.e. callable like a function.

Back to your example: Let's assume the DI framework provides you with an object of type `ImageUseCase` in a variable, let's call it `allImages`. Then that variable is - of course - of type `ImageUseCase` and you can access all properties and functions that are available on this type. Nothing special so far. So this is perfectly valid and does exactly what one expects:

```
allImages.invoke()
```

This works the same with or without the `operator` modifier. With the modifier, however, you can also use the following syntax:

```
allImages()
```

It works the same, but it *looks* different: `allImages` seems to be a function that can be executed, not a simple object (which it actually is).

It works because the compiler can detect that you try to execute (signalled by the parentheses) something that is an object. Usually it would abort with an error, because only functions can be executed. However, the compiler sees that the invoke operator is available on the object and executes that function instead.

All this may seem like a minor benefit at the cost of confusing objects with functions, but when used properly - as it is in your example - it can reduce the cognitive complexity because it enables you to handle the use case object as what it semantically really is: Just a function. You don't need the class, you do not need the object, you just want to call the function.

Comment: Thank you, Leviathan, for helping me understand the reason for having an operator in the ImageUseCase.

Answer (score 0):

You said you looked through Kotlin docs, so I assume you read the article about [operator overloading](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html) already. If you still don't get it, then maybe this is because the article doesn't explain the concept of operators itself, probably assuming the reader knows the concept from other programming languages.

The idea is simple: similarly as we can do e.g.: `4 + 5` or `myArray[3]`, which represents simple math and array operations, we sometimes would like to do: `myObject1 + myObject2` or `myObject[3]`. In other words, we would like our custom class to act as it is an array, we would like to provide math operations for it, allow to invoke it, etc.

Languages often provide this functionality by the compiler which translates these special language constructs into function calls, for example:

- `x + y` -> `x.plus(y)`
- `x[y]` -> `x.get(y)`
- `x(y)` -> `x.invoke(y)`.

Therefore, in order to provide such special treatment to our custom classes, we just need to provide implementations of operators in the form of regular functions:

```kotlin
class MyClass {
    // allows to do: myObj1 + myObj2 which translates to myObj1.plus(myObj2)
    operator fun plus(y: MyClass) = ...

    // allows to do: myObj[5] which translates to myObj.get(5)
    operator fun get(y: Int) = { ... }
}
```

We use the `operator` keyword to be explicit that this is an implementation of an operator and not just a regular function named `get` or `plus`. Still, we can call operators as regular functions: `myObj1.get(5)`.

Operator overloading is a so called [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar). Both `x[y]` and `x.get(y)` mean exactly the same thing. Languages sometimes provide alternative syntax for common operations in order to allow writing more concise and readable code.

See:

- https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar

Comment: Thanks broot, for the answer, and yeah I already looked at docs and operator overloading, but the docs do not explain it completely. maybe they say, that " if it is an operator then it is an operator so there is no need for further explanation"

Answer (score -2):

There's [a wikipedia article about operators here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_(computer_programming)).

Basically, *operators* are those of the programming language built-ins that do something (not 100% accurate, but almost), so `+`, `-`, `<`, `=`, `>=` etc.

Operator overloading is very convenient in some cases. If you have the string `"4"` and another string `"8"`, you could overload the plus operator and decide that `"4" + "8"` should yield `"12"` instead of `"48"`. (Not a very realistic example, you hopefully a good illustration.)